# In Oracle Trace file, how to interpret multiple PARSE / EXEC / CLOSE for single cursor?

Tags: oracle12c, exadata

I'm trying to decipher some Oracle trace files and I'm unsure how to interpret multiple PARSE / EXEC / CLOSE statements for what looks like a single cursor.  Something like the following:

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #1
*statement*
END OF STMT
PARSE #1
BINDS #1
*bindings*
EXEC #1
FETCH #1
CLOSE #1
PARSE #1
BINDS #1
*bindings*
EXEC #1
FETCH #1
CLOSE #1
PARSE #1
BINDS #1
*bindings*
EXEC #1
FETCH #1
CLOSE #1
```

And so on.  I count well over a dozen of these without a repeated PARSING IN statement.  How should I interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

It looked weird at first. I did not see this in a raw trc file before. However, it’s NOT a raw trace file.
The trace output shown here seems to have been generated via `TRCSESS` utility. `TRCSESS` consolidates trace output from multiple / selected trace files based on user-specified criteria. Thereafter, TRCSESS merges the trace information into a single output file.

This seems to be the only possibility why we get to see multiple ‘PARSE #’ in output.

Another observation, do you really need 10046 trace at level 12 ? The trace level looks at level 12 (with detailed bind variable info).